# minitest - expect a method to be called when it was extended from a Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, ruby-mocha

I am writing a test for the following code:

```
module Clockwork
  every(10.minutes, SomeBackgroundJob)
end
```

`every` is an instance method of the `Clockwork::Methods` module.

In RSpec I can write the following to test that a module method gets called:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Clockwork::Methods).to(
  receive(:every).with(10.minutes, SomeBackgroundJob)
)
```

However I'm not sure how do to this in minitest/mocha.

I am trying the following:

```
class ClockTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "it calls the job" do
    module ::Clockwork; module Methods; end; end
    Clockwork::Methods.any_instance.expects(:every).with(
      10.minutes,
      SomeBackgroundJob
    )
    require './clock.rb'
  end
end
```

With this code I am getting `undefined method any_instance`. I think it is because `Clockword::Methods` is a module and `any_instance` is only defined on classes. What is the proper Minitest/mocha approach to this? I just want to check that the method is called, I don't want it to actually run though.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the expectation on the module with something like ´Clockwork::Methods.expects(:every).with(10.minutes, SomeBackgroundJob)´?

Comment: @max in that case it shows that the method was never invoked.